# Unable to load Image asset exception thrown in Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

Here's my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('I AM RICH'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[900],
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Image(
          image: AssetImage('images/diamond.png'),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    ),
  );
}
```

THIS IS THE EXCEPTION I AM GETTING.

My pubspec.yaml file follows proper indentation.

```
======= Exception caught by image resource service ================================================
The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset: images/diamond.png

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:224:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:672:14)
<asynchronous suspension>
Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "images/diamond.png")
Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#a2375(), name: "images/diamond.png", scale: 1.0)
====================================================================================================
```

Comment: can you update your pubspec.yaml?

Comment: can you post your pubspec file source code? again are you sure the file is in the folder images?

Comment: sometime your pubsyaml ok but still you cant load image then flutter clean and run your project its work for me hopefully its will also work for you

Comment: well, if everything is fine, then you just need to stop and run your application again. That's it.

Comment: stopping the application and re-running it did not work

Comment: It means you have a problem either in pubspec.yaml file or with the image and its directory. After clicking on Pub get, what code it gives?

Comment: it executes with an exit code 0

Comment: @PrachikKumarChhapadia do mark my answer as accepted if it helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your image is under the `assets` folder. So, you need to call image like this:

```
AssetImage('assets/images/diamond.png')
```

And be sure that you wrote this correctly in your `pubspec.yaml`:

```
assets:
  - assets/images/
```

Comment: No. the 'image' folder is in the root project folder.

Comment: Then move it under the assets folder.

Comment: shall I create a new assets folder and move the images folder into it?

Comment: well, you don't need to move your file. images folder in root is okay, but do mention the folder in pubspec.yaml file in the correct way. I mean the indentations and directory name. After editing pubspec.yaml, do not forget to click on Pub get and it should give you exit code 0 in the message section. After that, do not forget to stop and re-run your application.

Answer (score 1):

make changes in your `pubspec.yaml` file

add this line to import all the files present in `images` folder

```
assets:
    - images/
```

for showing image you can use any one of the code shown below

```
Image(image: AssetImage('images/diamond.png')),
```

or

```
Image.asset('images/diamond.png'),
```

Answer (score 1):

Add asset path in pubspec.yaml as

```
assets:
  - images/diamond.png
```

or you can also add parent folder path

```
assets:
  - images/
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my pubspec.yaml file:

```
name: i_am_rich
description: Show off your wealth.

publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - images\
```

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately the problem is with typing mistake, **"images" should be "images/"**
Interesting how pub get executes with an exit code of 0 even after typing error.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, and stoping and restarting my app worked for me